# Printing on Plastic - How is this being done?

Tags: print-design, painting, vinyl

Can someone here tell me how the images are being printed on plastic?

Example:

[image: Plastic printing example]
<sup>Source: http://www.metalgearinformer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/PlayStation-4-HDD-Cases-MGSV-Ground-Zeroes.jpg</sup>

From what I have read, printing on plastic is not easy as the paint has very little to stick to.

So does anyone have any insight into how the above is being done?

Can one use hydrographics for static images (e.g. not patterns) to transfer a photo to plastic?

Comment: Typically screenprinted

Answer (score 5):

This kind of thing is typically screen printed for large quantities. However, for prototyping or for small runs that don't justify the cost of screen printing, a UV-cured flatbed printers can be used. We use ours to print onto plastic and metal all the time with no ink adhesion issues. Just find a sign maker near you and tell them what you're trying to do. When all else fails, you can use contour-cut vinyl or a transparent decal to fake it.